# How to integrate Azure AD SSO in flutter app

Tags: authentication, flutter, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I want to add authentication with SSO using azure AD in flutter app.But I didn't find any helpful doc for integration with flutter.So any suggestion will be of great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there is no native SDK for Flutter to integrate with AAD.

[Here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/aad_oauth#-readme-tab-) is a Flutter OAuth package for performing user authentication against Azure Active Directory OAuth2 V2.0 endpoint.

Regarding Single sign-on, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on).

Comment: I didn't find any package for v1.0 endpoint. You can find the difference between v1.0 endpoint and v2.0 endpoint here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison If you must use the v1.0 endpoint, I am afraid there is no such package currently.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, if you are still looking. May be this will be useful for others. Build Azure B2C service authentication
https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_appauth
Full application code can be found here https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/connecting-flutter-to-azure-ms-ignite/