# Flutter mobile app login via azure Active directory from web app that already implemented Azure Ad

Tags: azure, flutter, azure-active-directory, identity

I have a web app that already configured with Azure Ad, once user login the web app via azure ad, they web app will redirect it to identity server and then successfully logged in to the website. However, currently we have to implement the azure ad login in our flutter mobile app also. For calling the web app API, we have to get access token generated from the web app identity server. So the problem is that is there a solution to directly allow my mobile app to login through the azure ad page configured for my web app and get access token directly in my flutter app? Or is there other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving access token directly from the web api through AAD identity authentication and passing it to the flutter app for authentication purposes isn't possible. Though, you can add/show a redirect URL or callback url  link to the flutter app in your web app display api which is registered in azure app registration portal  such that when a user tries to log in to flutter app, it will be redirected to the flutter app site and in the flutter app backend, you can configure it to federate with AAD for authentication and authorization purpose.

**References:**

1. [flutter_aad_oauth](https://github.com/p-stannis/flutter_aad_oauth/blob/master/README.md)
2. [How to integrate Azure AD SSO in flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116271/how-to-integrate-azure-ad-sso-in-flutter-app)

You can also raise a support request if needed via overview page in portal> support + troubleshooting >new support request

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The way I did was exactly in your suggestion where once user click a button in my flutter mobile app, the browser will open up a web app login page which we have configured for our web app. From there, we have a button to sign in via azure ad . Once user successfully sign in via azure ad, the web app was configured with settings where the callback url is back to identity server. In this way , I am able to get identity server token from my web app immediately instead of azure ad. I actually use flutter appauth for this implementation.